# getRecyclerView returns null object

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a View from code for a Fragment, where I had it inflate in the standard way. In the onCreateView from the Fragment I changed

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
    mDragListView = (DragListView) view.findViewById(dlid); //R.id.drag_list_view
    mDragListView.getRecyclerView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

to

```
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    DragListView dlv = new DragListView(getActivity());
    int dlid = View.generateViewId();
    dlv.setId(dlid);
    rl.addView(dlv);
    View view = rl;
    mDragListView = (DragListView) view.findViewById(dlid); 
    mDragListView.getRecyclerView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

with the list_layout being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:id ="@+id/viewer_layout">

<com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drag_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In the second version it throws the stated error, that getRecyclerView() returns a nullobject, where it worked in the first version.

Help is appreciated and cheers

**EDIT**: could it be possible via [this](http://www.marioalmeida.eu/2015/01/27/how-to-easy-way-load-apk-classes-using-dexclassloader/), that I can load the layout, when I inflate it in the "method" in ClassToBeImported.class?

Comment: Change from `int dlid = View.generateViewId();` to `int dlid = dlv.generateViewId();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
```

in the new version. All layout elements will be null without it.

**EDIT:**
Since you already have a reference to the DragListView, you can use the instead of calling

```
view.findViewById(dlid);
```

Also return `rl` from `onCreateView` method.

**EDIT2**

If you have a local copy of `DragListView` implementation, try adding call to `onFinishInflate` in the constructor, so that it works when created from code as well.

```
public DragListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        onFinishInflate();
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to call it, because i dont want to use list_layout.

Comment: i am sorry, i dont quiet get, what you try to say in your edit. what you are saying about returning rl, i know. the error throws, when i try to invoke something on the RecyclerView.

Comment: In the `DragListView` class, the RecyclerView is instantiated in the `onFinishInflate` method. Since in your second case layout is not being inflated from xml, this method is never called. So RecyclerView remains `null`

Comment: ahh thats a well founded information :) is there another way, to initiate onFinishInflate, without inflating it from the xml? i guess not .-.

Comment: @JacobusConradi try out the way I mentioned in the edit. Worth a shot.

Comment: it is part of a library, so i guess that is not an option for me. Ill check if I can call it from my onCreateView, but i doubt it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98104/discussion-between-roshan-and-jacobus-conradi).